# Write a program that takes a user's input and compares it to words in a file

Tags: c, while-loop

I am in school and got an assignment to write a C program that takes an input from a user then scans a file and returns how many times that word shows up in a file.  I feel like I got it 90% done, but for some reason I can't get the while loop.  When I run the program it crashes at the while loop.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

  char input[50], file[50], word[50];
  int wordcount;
  printf("Enter a string to search for\n");
  scanf("%s", input);
  printf("Enter a file location to open\n");
  scanf("%s", file);
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen("%s", "r", file);

  while (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF) {
    if (strcmp(word, input)) {
      printf("found the word %s\n", input);
      wordcount++;
    }
  }
  printf("The world %s shows up %d times\n", input, wordcount);

  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering how it got compiled. Doesn't [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) take only two arguments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

```
fp = fopen("%s", "r", file);
```

is incorrect, [`fopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) expects only two arguments, not three. The correct version
is

```
fp = fopen(file, "r");
```

Note that there is no feature in the C language that allows you to construct
strings from variables like this `"%s", variable`<sup>1</sup>. This only works for function
like `printf` that read a format and interpret the format base on a fix set of
rules you can see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

The second problem is this:

```
if (strcmp(word, input))
```

`strcmp` is used to compared two strings, however it return 0 when the strings
are equal, non-zero otherwise. So the correct check should be

```
if(strcmp(word, input) == 0)
{
    printf("found the word %s\n", input);
    wordcount++;
}
```

One last thing: when you read a string with `scanf`, you should limit the amount
of characters to be read, otherwise you will overflow the buffer and this yield
undefined behaviour which could lead to a segfault.

`input` is a `char[50]`, so it can hold at most 49 characters, the better
`scanf` call would be

```
scanf("%49s", input);
```

with this you are making sure not to write beyond the bounds of the array.

---

**Fotenotes**

<sup>1</sup>The string `"%s"` has no real meaning in the C language, like any
other string it is merly a sequence of characters that ends with the
`'\0'`-terminating character. The memory layout for this strings is

```
+---+---+----+
| % | s | \0 |
+---+---+----+
```

The `printf` family of functions however give certains sequences of characters
(the ones beginning with `%`) a well defined meaning. They're used to determine the type of the variable that should
be used when printing as well as other format options. See [the `printf` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for more information about that. You have to
remember however, that this type of constructs only works with `printf` because
`printf` was design to work this way.

If you need to construct a string using values of other variables, then you need
to have an array with enough space and use a function like `sprintf`. For
example:

```
const char *base = "records";
int series = 8;

char fn[100];
sprintf(fn, "%s%d.dat", base, series);

// now fn has the string "records8.dat"

FILE *fp = fopen(fn, "r");
...
```

But in your case this is unnecessary because the whole filename was already
stored in variable `file`, so construction a new string based on `file` is not
needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a file named "%s", which I'm pretty sure does not exist.  If you had checked the return from `fopen`, you could have figured it out yourself.